# datatables-treegrid not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, treegrid

I am using datatable plugin [datatables-treegrid](https://github.com/homfen/dataTables.treeGrid.js) to make Tree Grid, But its not working for `children` data

```js
var dataSet = [
            {
                "name":"Test1",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "Test 11 ",
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name":"Test2",
            }
        ];
        var columns = [
            {
                title: '',
                target: 0,
                className: 'treegrid-control',
                data: function (item) {
                    if (item.children) {
                        return '<span>+</span>';
                    }
                    return '';
                }
            },
            {
                title: 'Name',
                target: 1,
                data: function (item,key) {
                    return item.name;
                }
            },
        ];
        $('#example').DataTable({
            'select': {
                'style': 'multi',
                'selector': 'td:not(:first-child)'
            },
            'columns': columns,
            'data':dataSet,
            'treeGrid': {
                'left': 10,
                'expandIcon': '<span>+</span>',
                'collapseIcon': '<span>-</span>'
            }
        });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-treegrid/0.2.0/js/jquery.treegrid.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>



<table id="example">

  </table>
```

I am trying to do somthing like this example : http://homfen.me/dataTables.treeGrid.js/

What I am missing here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @Niklesh I am facing the same issue.The value is never showing. How did you resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

I tried your code and got it working with a little change. Also my included libraries differ a little from yours (but I think that's not the reason).

```
<script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="dataTables.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="dataTables.treeGrid.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The order of inclusion is essential. If you include treeGrid before datatables, it won't work properly and before all you have to include jquery, which you already correctly did first. When I included treeGrid before dataTables, the children wouldn't expand, so it seems that this might be your solution right there.

Best regards,
Chris

Answer (score 1):

TreeGrid v1.1.0 does not support latest version of DataTables (v1.10.19 as of now). It supports v1.10.13.

But there is one fix I made on TreeGrid.js so that i am able to run it propery. Find the event handler below in the code and change the lines as described.

```
// Expand TreeGrid
        dataTable.on('click', 'td.treegrid-control', function (e) {
            if (!$(this).html()) {
                return;
            }
            var tr = $(this).closest('tr[role="row"]');

            // record selected indexes
            var selectedIndexes = [];
            select && (selectedIndexes = dataTable.rows({selected:true}).indexes().toArray());
            var tr = $(this).closest('tr[role="row"]'); //ADD THIS LINE
            var row = dataTable.row(tr); //CHANGE THIS LINE FROM var row = dataTable.row(this); //"this" selects the cell, not the row!!!
            var index = row.index();
            var data = row.data();
```